# Parse uuid from parameterized route path in falcon

Tags: python, uuid, falconframework

I have a `falcon` app with a parameterized route for getting resources. The user does not know the `uuid` of the resource because it is temporary, so a redirect is needed.

The user will make a GET /transaction request, and a redirect to the returned path of 302 found response.

How can I parse the uuid from the request path?

The app would look like this:

```
api = falcon.API()
api.add_route('/transaction', Transaction)
api.add_route('/transaction/{id}', TransactionItem))
```

And the recources something like this:

```
class Transaction(object):    

    def on_get(self, req, resp):     
        id = get_current_id()
        resp.status = falcon.HTTPFound('/TransactionItem/{}'.format(id))

class TransactionItem(object):
    def on_get(self, req, resp):
        // Parse id from path?
        transaction = get_transaction(id)
        // ...
        // include info in the response, etc
        resp.status = falcon.HTTP_200
```

Comment: em... as I know Flacon has this https://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/routing.html#falcon.routing.UUIDConverter  
it allows falcon to do this conversion for You. Just read the doc :). The macthed part is then passed in `**kwargs`, so You just do  `kwargs.get('id')`. So You must extend the method to `on_get(self, req, resp,*args,**kwargs)`

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I read the docs but could not understand the way of doing it. Actuallly I just [found](https://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/1.1.0/user/tutorial.html#serving-images) that you can do this directly `def on_get(self, req, resp, id):`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so.

Flacon passes the matched route **fields** as a keywords arguments. That means thats in Your `TransactionItem` class Your `on_get` must have **one of the** (You can chose one which is more clear for You) given definitions :

```
# 1st way
def on_get(self, req, resp, id=None):
    ...

# 2nd way (**kwargs catches all keywords args)
def on_get(self, req, resp, **kwargs):
    id = kwargs.get('id')
```

The passed **field** will be dafault passed as `str` if You want to have it converted by falcon You can use the builtin in Falcon `UUIDConverter`

Here the docs for converter : https://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/routing.html#falcon.routing.UUIDConverter